# Organize libraries and resources in an executable .JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries, directory-structure

I want to re-organize all files in my executable .JAR (resources, external librairies, and application .class files) using Eclipse.

What I have :

```
My.JAR

> folder "com" for external library 1 (com.apple.***)

> folder "org" for external library 2 (org.javasypt.***)

> folder "main" (package)
    >> .class files

> folder "resources"
    >> all resources files (images, texts...)

> folder "META-INF"
    >> "MANIFEST.MF" file
```

What I want to have :

```
My.JAR

> folder "main" 
    >> folder "resources"
        >>> all resources files

    >> folder "libraries"
        >>> external library 1 (com.apple.***)
        >>> external library 2 (org.javasypt.***)

    >> .class files

> folder "META-INF"
    >> "MANIFEST.MF" file
```

Is it possible to obtain this ? Thanks !

Comment: A) Why do you care what the JAR stucture looks like? Usually the only "client" of a JAR is the JVM that's loading it. B) Do you expect that custom structure to be loadable by a JVM?

Comment: A) Actually it's just to have an organized structure, and to know if it was possible to do so..
b) Yes, of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the [JAR file specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) dictates a specific structure. You're trying to mix organization-for-humans and organization for the runtime, but those two concepts are distinct. By all means, organize your source as you see fit, but you can't expect the runtime (JVM) to understand any arbitrary structure. That's why build tools (gradle, maven, ant, etc) exist to help produce the JAR specification structure exactly.

Realize that in your example, `org` and `com` are not really folders, they're they're nodes (levels) in package structures. Same for your `main` - it's just a package.

`resources` is the only thing that you have some flexibility, as you can name that whatever you want as long as the code that is reading content from it knows that name to expect.

`META-INF` and the manifest file are dictated by the spec and can't be changed or relocated.

Comment: Thanks ! I know what files/folders/packages are and what they are used for,  but I was just expecting re-organize all the structure.. I'll see what graden or maven offers to build what I want !

Comment: I think you misunderstand the answer. The point of the answer is the JAR structure is specified in detail, you can't deviate that much. A JAR that looks like what you proposed above is not a valid JAR and won't be usable by the JVM.

Comment: Okay, so I will let my JAR like this ! Thanks !